# Excel VBA Combo Box returning index not value

Tags: combobox, excel, vba

I've got a combo box set up in Excel 2007 which gathers its list items from another sheet. When I try to access the value of the selected item through a macro all I am returned is the index value and not the actual value.

```
DateDropDown = Sheets("Input Form").Shapes("APPDateDropDown").ControlFormat.Value
```

The value in the combo box is listed as "Jan-12" but when I run the code above DateDropDown is returned as 37 (the index of the item).

How do I get it to return the value "Jan-12"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
With Sheets("Input Form").Shapes("APPDateDropDown")
    DateDropDown = .ControlFormat.List(.ControlFormat.ListIndex)
End With
```

Comment: Thank You very much!! Was banging my head against a wall on this one.

Comment: Yeah form controls can be a pain sometimes :)